# How to hide or configure type labels when using Neovim+Treesitter+Rust

Tags: neovim

I installed Rust language support to Neovim's Treesitter via `:TSInstall rust`. All works well, but now there are extra labels showing the type to the right side of each variable assignment.

[image: Image showing '>hello: &str' to right side of variable assignment]

While I see the utility of this, I would like to hide/toggle or configure these to be far less intrusive. I can't find any documentation in the [tree-sitter-rust](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-rust) repo for this behavior. Many google searches have also failed to uncover mention of or hooks into these.

- What are these labels called so I can find documentation on them?
- How to I hide/toggle these labels?
- What highlighting group do they belong to (if any) so that I can configure their appearance?
- Is this specific to `tree-sitter-rust` or to Neovim's Treesitter more broadly (so that I can find documentation and if needed, open an issue). It seems odd that a default behavior changes the look of my editor without having prominent documentation.

Comment: I think theyre sometimes called « hints », « overlays », things like that.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out they're called [inlay hints](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#inlay-hints), and they're from rust-analyzer. I just didn't know about them until migrating to neovim. You can disable them with `"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.enable": false` (I'm using coc, so `:CocConfig`). Here are some [other setting options](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/inlay-hints-using-coc-nvim-neovim-and-rust-analyzer/42930/6).

Comment: Apparently in VSCode you can change the color with `rust_analyzer.inlayHints.foreground` ([source](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/issues/4334#issuecomment-876168693)). Apparently in neovim they are [virtual text](https://jdhao.github.io/2021/09/09/nvim_use_virtual_text/) (From the [rust-analyzer](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/blob/06ea89d3de66538a1d2352eb23ca57c03aa51713/crates/ide/src/inlay_hints.rs#L35) codebase: "Editors usually render this using read-only virtual text snippets interspersed with code.") Still figuring out how to change the color in neovim

Comment: Here is the [Lua code](https://github.com/nvim-lua/lsp_extensions.nvim/blob/4011f4aec61ba59c734f5dbf52e91f258b99d985/lua/lsp_extensions/inlay_hints.lua) for inlay hints, specifically mentioning Rust Analyzer. I'll write or accept an answer when I discover the highlight group ([determined here](https://github.com/nvim-lua/lsp_extensions.nvim/blob/4011f4aec61ba59c734f5dbf52e91f258b99d985/lua/lsp_extensions/inlay_hints.lua#L47)?), at least for a Coc-Nvim+coc-rust-analyzer setup. Thanks again to Ben for pointing the way.

Comment: yes please compile this information into an answer